# Stop fminsearch when objective function reach certain value

Tags: matlab, optimization, fminsearch

How to stop fminsearch when objective function exceeded certain value (minima or maxima)

```
options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',9999);
[x,fval,exitflag,output]  =  fminsearch(@(var)objectiveFunction(variables), changingParameters,options);
```

How to stop the function if I reach certain objective function value (for example 1000) [within the 9999 iterations]

I've tried `'TolFun'` , I am not sure if this is correct

```
options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',999,'TolFun',1000);
[x,fval,exitflag,output]  =  fminsearch(@(var)objectiveFunction(variables), changingParameters,options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually stop the search procedure by placing an appropriate function in the `options.OutputFcn` input struct.  This function is called in every iteration of the search, and permits to signal back that the search is to be terminated.  For example, you could define

```
function stop = custom_stop_fun(~, optimValues, ~)
if optimValues.fval >= 1000
    stop = true;
else
    stop = false;
end
end
```

and then set it via

```
options.OutputFcn = @custom_stop_fun;
```

Check out the full `OutputFcn` [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/output-functions.html)